# How to prove the following full rank condition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with positive values.
Let $v$ be a vector of length $m$ with positive values.

Consider the following function of $x$, a vector of length $n$, such that $x_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_i x_i = 1$ (i.e. the following function is defined only for $x$ which satisfies the above conditions):

$$f(x) = \sum_i v_i \log \left( \sum_j x_j A_{ij} \right)$$

I want to show that if $A$ is full rank then $f$ is injective (by that I mean that $x \neq x'$ means $f(x) \neq f(x')$).

Pretty sure it is true, not sure how to show it. I have a feeling tht it is also a necessary condition "almost".

EDIT: I may be missing here a condition on $m$ and $n$ and the relationship between them ($n \ge m$? $m \ge n$? Probably need $m \ge n$, but maybe there is no need for anything like that.)

EDIT 2: My sense now from reading online is that one way to do that would be to calculate the gradient and show that something holds for it. If $f(x)$ was univariate, then you would just need to show $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x) < 0$, which makes sense. What would you need to show the gradient upholds for a multivariate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

\begin{align*}
f(e_1) &= \sum_{i=1}^2 v_i \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_1)_j A_{ij} \right) \\
&= \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_1)_j A_{1j} \right) + \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_1)_j A_{2j} \right) \\
&= \log A_{11} + \log A_{21} = \log 2 + \log 1, \\
f(e_2) &= \sum_{i=1}^2 v_i \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_2)_j A_{ij} \right) \\
&= \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_2)_j A_{1j} \right) + \log \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 (e_2)_j A_{2j} \right) \\
&= \log A_{12} + \log A_{22} = \log 1 + \log 2.
\end{align*}

So, no, I don't think $f$ needs to be injective.

Comment: You are right. I think all I need is for it to have a unique maximum, and I shouldn't be interested in this kind of injectivity. Thanks.